# Do the angels in heaven ever get scared of the thunders and lightnings proceeding from the great white throne?

Tags: heaven, angels, ministry

I have read the scripture and learnt that spiritual entities like the demons are capable of emotions of fear, this can be validated by the Biblical verse where The **Holy Spirit speaking through the mouth of Saint James** says that even the devils know that God is One and they tremble.

**James 2:19**

> You believe that God is one; you do well. Even the demons believe  and tremble

And since the devils are fallen angels the it follows that even the angels who kept their former state are capable of the same emotions.

Now lightnings and thunders proceed from the Great White Throne, and around the Throne are **millions of angels**.

**Revelation 5:11-12**

> Then I looked, and I heard around the throne and the living creatures and the elders the voice of many angels, numbering myriads of myriads and thousands of thousands, saying with a loud voice

And the Biblical basis for the thunders and lightnings proceeding from the GWT

**Revelation 4:5**

> From the throne came flashes of lightning, and rumblings and peals of thunder, and before the throne were burning seven torches of fire, which are the seven spirits of God,

Do these angels ever experience the same fear and if that is so, how can they serve God out love?

Comment: I don't think there's any Biblical or other writing that addresses this quesiton.

Comment: @Maverick, okay that's you throwing in the towels, some other user might have the Biblical basis

Comment: I'm sorry you didn't like my comment. Good luck finding your answer.

Comment: @Maverick, I didn't express dislike for your comment. I just said you give in too easily without at least trying. There is always an answer

Comment: I'm sorry you think I give in to easily and don't try. I gave in because I've read the book and find no reference to angels being afraid. Good luck finding your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Book of Revelation contains John's description of what he saw in a vision, described in his own words based on his own experience.

To him, whatever was happening at the throne could best be compared with earthly thunder and lightning.

But to spirit beings, what was happening could have been perceived as something completely different, and not understood as anything frightening at all.

Compare with the term "iron horse", from 150 years ago.
A railroad train is not a horse, but people used that expression because it enabled them to convey the unfamiliar concept using familiar words.